# How to use localStorage in Nuxt.js store

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm working on a nuxt.js project.here, i want to use `localStorage` inside `Nuxt-Store` and also want to access the `localStorage` value from `Nuxt-Middleware`. it's show an error.

> localStorage is not defined.

How can i solve this problem ?

Here, code sample of **`store/index.js`**

```
setUser(state, { user }){
    state.user = user
    state.isLoggedIn = true
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', state.isLoggedIn);
},
```

my **middleware** code is here-

```
export default function({ store, redirect, route}) {
const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
const loggedStatus = store.getters['isLoggedIn']

if (user) {
    if(route.path == '/login' || route.path == '/user/temporary'){
        return redirect('/')
    } 
       return 
}


if(!user){
    return redirect('/login')
}

}
```

Comment: `localStorage` is *local* to the browser, you can not access it in server-side code. That is why you have `store`.

Comment: if, i'm not able to use in server-side. can i use it from front-end and middleware ?

Answer (score 5):

In order to run this code on the client side **only**, you'll need to add some logic to your middleware.  Check the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware) to read more.

> In universal mode, middlewares will be called server-side once (on the first request to the Nuxt app or when page refreshes) and client-side when navigating to further routes. In SPA mode, middlewares will be called client-side on the first request and when navigating to further routes.

Add the following to your middleware function:

```
export default function({ store, redirect, route }) {

  // Do not run on server
  if (process.server) {
    return
  }

  const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
  const loggedStatus = store.getters['isLoggedIn']

  if (user) {
    if (route.path == '/login' || route.path == '/user/temporary') {
      return redirect('/')
    }
    return
  }

  if (!user) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

If you're running in SPA mode, then you're done.  This middleware will only be run on the client on every single load, initial and while navigating between pages.

Now, if you're running in universal mode, this middleware will not be run on the server anymore, but it also won't be run on the first application load.

> In universal mode, middlewares will be called server-side **once** (on the first request to the Nuxt app or when page refreshes) and client-side when navigating to further routes

The easiest way to get around this is to also add a plugin that is only run on the client.  Taken from [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2653#issuecomment-390588837) issue, add this plugin to your `nuxt.config.js`, taking care to add the .client postfix:

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    // .client will only be run client side on initial app load
    '~/plugins/init.client.js'
  ]
}
```

And inside this plugin, you can define the same logic that your middleware has:

```
// /plugins/init.client.js
export default function({ store, redirect, route }) {

  const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
  const loggedStatus = store.getters['isLoggedIn']

  if (user) {
    if (route.path == '/login' || route.path == '/user/temporary') {
      return redirect('/')
    }
    return
  }

  if (!user) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

This example flies in the face of DRY principles, and is intended as an example for working around the limitations of middleware in Nuxt.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution make it works, but it seems that there is a delay during commit local storage values to store. In fact, the view is loaded and then we can see after 0,5ms that plug in finished to set values to store.

Comment: Without any code examples, it's impossible to say for sure, but there's a couple things to check.  First, when you say "view", do you mean the component, or just the app?  Components are always loaded after all plugins are finished.  However, if you're doing anything async inside your plugin, you need to make sure to return a promise, otherwise the plugin chain won't wait.  This is likely what you're seeing if your component is indeed loading before your plugin is done.

Comment: Indeed, it is only the component that is rendered before the end of plugin on client side. In this plugin, it is only "localstorage.getitem" and "store.commit" nothing else

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins According to this, "The plugins directory contains JavaScript plugins that you want to run before instantiating the root Vue.js Application".  What you're describing is not the correct behaviour.  I'd recommend opening a new question with a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score -2):

You can directly make use of localStorage in nuxtjs.

```
this.$auth.$storage.setLocalStorage(key, val)
this.$auth.$storage.getLocalStorage(key)
this.$auth.$storage.removeLocalStorage(key)
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/storage/)

Comment: Seems not-right to use an auth module for this.

Comment: Bad solution for SSR