# How to use middlewares one more time in Nuxt.js universal mode?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, local-storage, middleware

I have middleware that I need to check if user authenticated every time he visits page. For now it seems like this, just to make sure if it's able to work with `localStorage`:

```js
export default function({ store, redirect, route }) {
  console.log('Here is auth middleware')
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/test.client.js'
  ],
```

Generally, this middleware has to work with `localStorage`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153979/how-to-use-localstorage-in-nuxt-js-store) I found solution of my problem, but it works only one time (from documentation):

> In universal mode, middlewares will be called server-side **once** (on the
> first request to the Nuxt app or when page refreshes) and client-side
> when navigating to further routes

So, I need to create such middleware, that is going to work only on **specific pages** and be able to work with `localStorage` with `Nuxt.js` app in **universal** mode. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved using `mixins`. In `mixins/auth.js` I have this code:

```js
import { verifyToken } from "@/api";
export default {
  async mounted() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      await this.$router.push({path: '/login'})
    } else {
      const checkToken = await verifyToken({ token: localStorage.getItem('token') })
      if (checkToken.error) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        await this.$router.push({path: '/login'})
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then, on page where I need to check is there is valid token in `localStorage` I just do this:

```js
<script>
import auth from '~/mixins/auth'
export default {
  name: "Component",
  mixins: [auth],
</script>
```